# React enzyme testing, Cannot read property 'have' of undefined

Tags: testing, reactjs, enzyme

I'm writing a test using [Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) for React.

My test is extremely straightforward:

```
import OffCanvasMenu from '../index';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

import expect from 'expect';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import React from 'react';

describe('<OffCanvasMenu />', () => {
  it('contains 5 <Link /> components', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<OffCanvasMenu />);
    expect(wrapper.find(<Link />)).to.have.length(5);
  });
});
```

This code is basically taken directly from [airbnb/enzyme docs](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md), but returns the error:

```
FAILED TESTS:
  <OffCanvasMenu />
    ✖ contains 5 <Link /> components
      Chrome 52.0.2743 (Mac OS X 10.11.6)
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined
```

I'm a little unclear on what I'm doing differently from the docs. Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use `Link` instead of `<Link />`:

```
describe('<OffCanvasMenu />', () => {
  it('contains 5 <Link /> components', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<OffCanvasMenu />);
    expect(wrapper.find(Link)).to.have.length(5);
  });
});
```

It appears in the 1st example in the airbnb/enzyme docs:

```
it('should render three <Foo /> components', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  expect(wrapper.find(Foo)).to.have.length(3);
});
```

The syntax `.to.have.length` is for the [Chai Assertion Library](https://www.chaijs.com/).  For [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) use `.toHaveLength`:

```
it('should render three <Foo /> components', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  expect(wrapper.find(Foo)).toHaveLength(3);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I see the same error with `Link`. And I'm following the docs, although the code I'm using imports Michael Jackson's `expect`, and I'm not sure if that's throwing it off (I've checked the docs there too).

Comment: What assertion library do you use?
Try this - `console.log('length', wrapper.find(Link).length);`, and see what appears in the console.

Comment: Adding this produces the expected entry in the log - "5". I'm using Karma with Chai, but with Michael Jackson's [expect](https://github.com/mjackson/expect).

Comment: So enzyme works fine. Try this - `expect(wrapper.find(Link).length).toBe(5);`. Don't use chai if you're using expect, they are doing the same thing.

Comment: That works perfectly.. I think I understand now, I'll refer to MJ's `expect` docs from now on.. Many thanks!

Comment: @OriDrori Hi! I had the same issue, and `expect(wrapper.find(Link).length).toBe(5);` solved it perf. Could you explain why `.to.have.length(3);` did not work?

Comment: @Mihir `to.have.length` is part of the chai syntax, while `.toBe(5)` is part of the expect syntax. So it depends on what you're using for assertions.

Comment: @OriDrori I suspected that! Thank you! It's very confusing.

Comment: @OriDrori Finally got my test to pass, thank you so much! Spent a couple hours on this and going through enzyme docs. Thank you!!

Answer (score 39):

In their documentation Enzyme is using Chai assertion, so if you want to use `expect(***).to.have.length(***)` you need to install `chai-enzyme` and use its `expect`. It will, therefore, lead to issues with `expect(***).toMatchSnapshot()` if you use Jest snapshots, but this [article](https://medium.com/@RubenOostinga/combining-chai-and-jest-matchers-d12d1ffd0303) will help you to solve it, so you can do both.

Comment: Thanks—this is helpful for us newbies who don't recognize the syntax from all the different libraries!

Answer (score 11):

This could be because you don't have the chai assertion library installed in your dependencies or have not imported it in your tests file. Therefore, You need to install chai-enzyme and import it in your test file i.e.

> npm install chai
>
> import { expect } from 'chai';

Comment: enzyme documentation doesn't say more about this. Is there any better tutorials for reactjs unit testing with enzyme, chai, and mocha?

Comment: hmmm.... it has a really bad docmentation for these testing libraries. plp mix them but their documentation doesn't consider any dependencies

Answer (score 3):

This error can happen when you've got a parenthesis misplaced such that `.to.have` incorrectly is placed within the parenthesis of `expect(...)`:

Correct:

```
expect(wrapper.find(<Link />)).to.have.length(5);
```

Causes *TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined*:

```
expect(wrapper.find(<Link />).to.have.length(5));
```